# android crash when trying to get extras.getLong

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have been trying for hours to figure out why android crashes after loading Profile activity. The line that is causing the issue is :

```
mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID): null;
```

located in Profile.java. so I have firstly

OvertheLimit.java which puts extras via a menu option intent:

```
package uk.co.obdesign.android.overthelimit;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Overthelimit extends ListActivity {
    private OverLimitDbAdapter dbHelper;
    private static final int USER_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int USER_EDIT = 1;
    private Cursor cursor;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.getListView();
        dbHelper = new OverLimitDbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();

    }
    private void fillData() {
        cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllUserDrinks();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);


        String[] from = new String[] { OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_USERNAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.user_row, cursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.profile:
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Overthelimit.this, Profile.class);
            myIntent1.putExtra(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)));
            startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.myusual:
            Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Overthelimit.this, MyUsual.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.trackme:
            Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(Overthelimit.this, TrackMe.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.moreinfo:
            Intent myIntent4 = new Intent(Overthelimit.this, MoreInfo.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent4, 0);
            return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (dbHelper != null) {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    }


}
```

then selecting the profile menu option     takes me to Profile, which crashes trying to get extras.
I have checked data using toast and it's there. any ideas?

```
package uk.co.obdesign.android.overthelimit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Profile extends Activity{
    private EditText mUserName;
    private RadioGroup mGender;
    private EditText mAge;
    private EditText mHeight;
    private EditText mWeight;
    private Spinner mDrinkerType;
    private Long mRowId;
    private OverLimitDbAdapter mDbHelper;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        mDbHelper = new OverLimitDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        mAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        mHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
        mWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        mGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender);


        mDrinkerType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.drinkerType);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextUsualDrinks);


                mRowId = (bundle == null) ? null :
                    (Long) bundle.getSerializable(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
                if (mRowId == null) {
                    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                    mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                            : null;
                }


            populateFields();

            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View view) {   
                 setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    //finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyUsual.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });


    }
    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor todo = mDbHelper.fetchUserDrinks(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(todo);

            mUserName.setText(todo.getString(todo
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_USERNAME)));
            String gender = todo.getString(todo
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_GENDER));


            // Returns an integer which represents the selected radio button's ID
             int selected = mGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // Gets a reference to our "selected" radio button
             RadioButton b = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);

            // Now you can get the text or whatever you want from the "selected" radio button
             String bn = (String) b.getText();

             if (bn.equalsIgnoreCase(gender)) {
                 if(gender == "male") 
                            ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male)).setChecked(true);
                 else if (gender == "female")
                            ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female)).setChecked(true);


             }


            mAge.setText(todo.getString(todo
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_AGE)));
            mHeight.setText(todo.getString(todo
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_HEIGHT)));
            mWeight.setText(todo.getString(todo
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_WEIGHT)));
            String drinkerType = todo.getString(todo
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE));

            for (int i = 0; i < mDrinkerType.getCount(); i++) {

                String s = (String) mDrinkerType.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Log.e(null, s + " " + drinkerType);
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(drinkerType)) {
                    mDrinkerType.setSelection(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }

    private void saveState() {
        String username = mUserName.getText().toString();

        // Returns an integer which represents the selected radio button's ID
         int selected = mGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        // Gets a reference to our "selected" radio button
         RadioButton b = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);
        // Now you can get the text or whatever you want from the "selected" radio button
        String gender = (String) b.getText();

        String age = mAge.getText().toString();
        String height = mHeight.getText().toString();
        String weight = mWeight.getText().toString();
        String type = (String) mDrinkerType.getSelectedItem();

        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createUserProfile(username, gender, age, height, weight, type);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateUserProfile(mRowId, username, gender, age, height, weight, type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the crash? Post stackTrace please..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, I have fixed this now as answers below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Overthelimit` class you set the value with the following line:

```
myIntent1.putExtra(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)));
```

This puts a **String** value into the intent extras. Trying to get the same value as a **Long** value will make you applications crash, as it does not exist as a Long value. If you instead convert the value you get from your cursor object (or gets it directly as a Long from your cursor), your application should not crash anymore. Alternatively, you can get your value from the intent extras by using `getString()`, not `getLong()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely that you add a `String` extra (as `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID))` returns a `String`) - but try to get a `Long` extra - which does not compute.

The following should fix the problem:

```
mRowId = extras != null ? Long.parseLong( extras.getString(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) ) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it giving type casting error as you store the value as string in put try to type cast at putting the value time or get the as string and then convert to long value but for type casting may be you getting type casting error in this so put into the try catch block and see the logcat details to detecting the error

type cast here from string to long or

```
myIntent1.putExtra(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)));
```

or get as string here and then type cast from string to long

```
String s = extras.getString(OverLimitDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
mRowId = extras != null ? Long.parseLong(s): null;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Used your second fix. Can't see wood for the trees.